# Rotating an object around a fixed point in opengl

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a problem with this openGL code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix(); // put current matrix on stack

//glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
//glTranslatef(-4*1.5, 0.0, 4*1.5);

glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // rotate the robot on its y-axis
glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos);
DrawRobot(xpos, ypos, zpos); // draw the robot
glPopMatrix();
```

What should I do to make my robot turn around the point at which it is currently situated and not around the origin? I think the problem lies in this snippet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply do the rotation after the translation. The order matters.

```
glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos);
glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Dude it worked Thanks but the problem is the circle around which robot is rotating ; i want to decrease its radius BTW i am rotating robot at 90 degrees only Awaiting ur reply THANX asap

Comment: @user2388112: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I think this should help: You can rotate around any point you want by first translating to that point, then rotating, then translate back (just take the negative of each coordinate). If that's not what you're looking for, please [ask a new question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as these comments aren't a good place for extended discussion.

Answer (score 17):

Example of rotating an object around its centre along the z-axis:

```
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(250,250,0.0); // 3. Translate to the object's position.

glRotatef(angle,0.0,0.0,1.0); // 2. Rotate the object.

glTranslatef(-250,-250,0.0); // 1. Translate to the origin.

// Draw the object
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: This question is old, and was already sufficiently answered. New answer does not add anything useful. And the same few lines of code were submitted as answer to other old questions.

Comment: This answer adds something new, namely that after the rotation, the object needs to be translated back to its original position. That was not mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: This worked for me. Didn't work without the Push and PopMatrix statements.

Answer (score 3):

try rotating after translation:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix(); // put current matrix on stack

//glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   
//glTranslatef(-4*1.5, 0.0, 4*1.5);

glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, zpos);
glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // rotate the robot on its y-axis
DrawRobot(xpos, ypos, zpos); // draw the robot
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Dude it worked Thanks but the problem is the circle around which robot is rotating ; i want to decrease its radius BTW i am rotating robot at 90 degrees only Awaiting ur reply THANX asap

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
house();

glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0); // 3. Translate back to original
glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // 2. Rotate the object around angle
glTranslatef(-m, -n, 0.0); // 1. Move to origin

house();
```

where **m and n** are the ***point on the object around which you want to rotate*** and
**x and y** are the ***points around which you want to rotate***.