# OpenGL: Moving a Triangle to a specific angle and rotate it around its origin point

Tags: c, opengl

I have the following triangle :

[image]

How to rotate the triangle around its **original point** ( e.g. on `R` pressed) and move it forward to the current direction ( e.g. on `UP` pressed) **(Like any game)**

I use the following and it works fine , but the problem is once I move the triangle a little bit and then rotate it , **it rotates around the origin point of the world not the center point of the triangle**.

```
// Drawing routine.
void drawScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(-_zangle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(_xTranslate,_yTranslate,0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3ub(255,0,0);
        glVertex2i( -100 , -50);

        glColor3ub(255,0,0);
        glVertex2i(100 , -50);

        glColor3f(255,255,255);
        glVertex2i( 0, 50);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your rotation after your translation:

```
glTranslatef(_xTranslate,_yTranslate,0);
glRotatef(-_zangle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

See [Rotating an object around a fixed point in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578027/rotating-an-object-around-a-fixed-point-in-opengl?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to my answer to another question ([Rotating an object around a fixed point using glMultMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442499/rotating-an-object-around-a-fixed-point-using-glmultmatrix/23448400#23448400)), and borrows some content from it.

The key point to understand is that the transformations are applied to your vertices **in reverse order** of the order you specify them in. The last transformation you specify is the first one that is applied to your vertices.

In your example, to rotate first, and then translate, you need to specify the translation first, and then the rotation:

```
glTranslatef(_xTranslate,_yTranslate,0);
glRotatef(-_zangle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```